# Logic Circuit Design

Tags: digital-logic

I am not Electrical engineer but I am taking digital logic classes. I have a homework but I didn't understand how to do it. This is the question :

The temperature control logic accepts an 8-bit code representing
measured temperature in binary. The measured temperature is compared with a specific field
temperature. Design and draw a logic circuit which produced “1” if these two binary values are
equal.

How can I compare if these values are equal? 8-bit means there are 8 inputs? I am really stuck here because nobody showed us similar problems in class. Can anybody help?

Comment: If you know how to detect if a single bit is different from another specific bit then perhaps you can expand that.. how far have you actually gotten on this?

Comment: Note that a equality comparison is not what a controller needs.  Can you see why?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I am planning to use XOR gate, when all bits are same result will be 00000000. If I use a inverter, and use AND gate, final result will be 1. Am I thinking correct ?

Comment: @Nick Your thinking is correct, but pay careful attention to Olin's comment about what you actually need to implement a control function. How would you do it manually?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany To be honest I am confused about that comment. Why we don't need a aquality comparison?

Comment: If you manually control temperature (say to 22.00 degrees C) what actions will you take if the temperature is 21.04, 22.01, 22.00, 21.94, 22.10 degrees C? Is equality (yes/no) enough information to make your control decision?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I think equality is enough because when a bit in input temperature is different from control temperature, logic gates will have result 0 in the end. Am I right?

Comment: No, an equality comparison is not enough to make a useful controller.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany can you give me a little hint? I am new in this logic topics.

Comment: If you are trying to control to 30.0 degC and the circuit tells you the temperature is not 30.0 degC, what do you do?  Do you turn on the heater or not?  Would your answer differ if you knew the temprature was actually 29 degC or 31 degC?

Comment: @OlinLathrop According to my assignment, I don't have to do anything if they are not equal. I just have to find if they are equal. Is there a way to find if input is higher or lower?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint #1: Break the problem down into chunks.** You have a system with two inputs (a measurement and a value to compare it with) and an output (a single bit). You know that you must compare the measurement and the value, and spit out a single bit indicating if the values are equal. So, at least you know that you need some comparison logic. You should also assume that your reference value is 8 bits since it's not explicitly specified - why complicate things?

**Hint #2: Think about how to implement these chunks with hardware.** For example, what does 'equal' actually mean? It means that all 8 bits of the measurement must match all 8 bits of the reference value. So, your next task is to figure out how to check those bits one by one, then figure out how to check the results of those checks to see if they all match, which (if you're clever) will be your single output bit.

Comment: I will use Exclusive-NOR to check if bits are equal. If both inputs are same, that logic gate will have 1 as result. After that, I will use AND gates to reduce input to single input. Is it correct?

Comment: You will find that there are *many* correct ways to solve problems. If the output gives you the correct result then it is correct logically, but there may be other solutions that also give the correct value.